# Can you choose which pictures to print on a Fuji Instax 210?

Tags: polaroid

I'm not sure if this option is available for this particular camera. I can't seem to find it in the specs. I don't want to have to waste photo papers.

Follow-up: can I store the captured pictures in a memory card for this particular camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choice is limited to when you press the shutter. This is not a digital camera, so there's no other review/print options other than the viewfinder/shutter. Given this is a film camera, there is no digital sensor nor memory card for review later - if you want to share your pictures online, you will need to scan them.